# Compile error on address.call

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-compile

My syntax seems to be ok, so I do not understand this CompileError[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My syntax seems to be ok

The compiler thinks otherwise :-)

You're missing some brackets `(` `)` around the curly braces...

```
(bool success) = address(parentContract).call({value: msg.value})(abi.encodeWithSignature("triggerPayment(uint256)", index));
```

Comment: Am encountering further issues ahead, shared in this post. I appreciate your help! https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93813/getting-multiple-errors-on-address-call-implementation

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the version of Solidity is correct. Changed in version 0.6.4, please try version 0.6.4 or higher.